# How to create a list of dictionaries using for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

Textfile:

```
VIP Room,      10,   250
Executive Room,30,   500
Pool Site,     50,   850
Banquet Hall,  200,  1000
Chamber Hall,  500,  2000
Concert Hall,  1000, 3500
```

My code so far to read the file and create a list:

```
def readVenueList():
    dic={}
    venueList=[]
    f=open("venue.txt","r")
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(",")
        print(line)
        for i in line:
            i.split()
            dic["name"]=i[0]
            dic["num"]=i[1]
            dic["cost"]=i[2]
            venueList.append(dic)
    return(venueList)
```

How do I create a list of dictionaries with the following output?

```
venueList = [{'cost': '250', 'name': 'VIP Room', 'num': '10'},
             {'cost': '250', 'name': 'Executive Room', 'num': '30'},
                # and so on and so forth...
            ]
```

Comment: You're very close... `i.split()` splits `i` but then throws away the resulting list because you don't assign it back to something. Your references to `i[0]` etc. are then references to the first few characters of the original line. Also, you should put your `dic` initialization within the loop so that you get a new dictionary for each line.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the csv reader library to handle this.

```
import csv
headers = ['name', 'num', 'cost']
with open('venue.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    needed_list = [{headers[i]: row[i].strip() for i in range(3)} for row in reader]
```

Comment: Be sure to `.strip()` the `row[i]`.  It looks like there is an extra space after the commas.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to earlier answer by @N M

```
datablob = u"""VIP Room,10,250
Executive Room,30,500
Pool Site,50,850
Banquet Hall,200,1000
Chamber Hall,500,2000
Concert Hall,1000,3500
"""
from csv import reader
from io import StringIO

def readVenueList(fd):
    c = reader(fd)
    hdr = ["name", "num", "cost"]
    for i in c:
        d = {}
        for el, v in enumerate(i):
            d[hdr[el]] = v
        yield d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # replace with file object
    # file = open("archive1.csv")
    file = StringIO(datablob)
    print(list(readVenueList(file)))
    # Output
    [{'name': 'VIP Room', 'num': '10', 'cost': '250'}, {'name': 
     'Executive Room', 'num': '30', 'cost': '500'}, {'name': 'Pool 
      Site', 'num': '50', 'cost': '850'}, {'name': 'Banquet Hall', 
     'num': '200', 'cost': '1000'}, {'name': 'Chamber Hall', 'num': 
     '500', 'cost': '2000'}, {'name': 'Concert Hall', 'num': '1000', 
     'cost': '3500'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a CSV reader (though that's probably the best idea), you could also do this using list/dictionary comprehensions

```
with open('venue.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = (line.split(',') for line in f)
    venues = [
        {'name': name.strip(), 'number': int(num), 'cost': int(cost)}
        for name, num, cost in lines
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to modify your code do it properly (and follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations more closely) :

```
from pprint import pprint

def readVenueList():
    venueList = []

    with open("venue.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            dic = {}
            items = [item.strip() for item in line.split(",")]
            dic["name"] = items[0]
            dic["num"] = items[1]
            dic["cost"] = items[2]
            venueList.append(dic)

    return venueList

venueList = readVenueList()
pprint(venueList)
```

Output:

```
[{'cost': '250', 'name': 'VIP Room', 'num': '10'},
 {'cost': '500', 'name': 'Executive Room', 'num': '30'},
 {'cost': '850', 'name': 'Pool Site', 'num': '50'},
 {'cost': '1000', 'name': 'Banquet Hall', 'num': '200'},
 {'cost': '2000', 'name': 'Chamber Hall', 'num': '500'},
 {'cost': '3500', 'name': 'Concert Hall', 'num': '1000'}]
```